# Rails 3 with composed_of model and validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, composition

I have this domain model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  composed_of :address,
              mapping: [%w(address_street street), %w(address_city city), %w(address_zip_code zip_code), %w(address_country country)]

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :surname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

  validates_associated  :address
end

class Address
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_reader :street, :city, :zip_code, :country

  validates :street, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
  validates :zip_code, presence: true
  validates :country, presence: true

  def initialize(street, city, zip_code, country)
    @street, @city, @zip_code, @country = street, city, zip_code, country
  end

  def ==(other_address)
    street == other_address.street && city == other_address.city && zip_code == other_address.zip_code && country == other_address.country
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

When I try to save an invalid model:

```
> p = Person.new
=> #<Person id: nil, name: nil, surname: nil, address_street: nil, address_city: nil, address_zip_code: nil, address_country: nil
> p.valid?
=> false
> p.errors
=> {:name=>["can't be blank"], :surname=>["can't be blank"], :address=>["is invalid"]}
```

This is ok, but I would prefer to have the error array filled with the error messages of Address, like this:

```
=> {:name=>["can't be blank"], :surname=>["can't be blank"], :address_street=>["can't be blank"], :address_city=>["can't be blank"], :address_zip_code=>["can't be blank"], :address_country=>["can't be blank"]}
```

The question is: is there a clean Rails way to do it? Or simply I have to move the validation code from Address to Person (pretty ugly)? Any other solution?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a `composed_of` attribute, it becomes an object on it's own. I see two ways to answer your need.

1) add error message in your `Address` class

Replace your current validations with:

```
validates_each :street, :city, :zip_code, :country do |record, attr, value|  
  record.errors.add attr, 'should not be blank' if value.blank?
end
```

This way, you'll be able to access the error messages doing:

```
p = Person.new
p.address.errors
```

2) Customize only the `address` error message

```
validates_associated  :address, 
                      :message => lambda { |i18n_key, object| self.set_address_error_msg(object[:value]) }

def self.set_address_error_msg address
  errors_array = Array.new
  address.instance_variables.each do |var|
    errors_array << "#{var[1..-1]} should not be blank" if address.send(var[1..-1]).blank?
  end
  errors_array.join(", ")
end
```

This would render something like:

```
=> #<OrderedHash {:address=>["country should not be blank, zip_code should not be blank, validation_context should not be blank, city should not be blank"]}>
```

Finally, you could rewrite validators in your `Profile` class but as you said it's really ugly.

Comment: I've ended with using `validates_each` and displaying errors in the forms with `<ul>
    <% (@person.errors.full_messages + @person.address.errors.full_messages).each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>`

Comment: Is there a better way to obtain all the errors of a model and all its composed_of objects?